# How can I get OS X El Capitan and watchOS and iOS 9 without being a developer?

Tags: beta-seed-program, watchos, macos, ios

I'm looking to get a hold of Apple's WWDC announced OSs in 2015 before they are released to everyone in the fall of 2015.

Can I get any or all without being a [paid developer](https://developer.apple.com/programs/)?

Comment: Why would you want to? Unless you are a developer and need to test your product against it, all you will get is a buggy, unstable, unfinished OS. If you are thinking you can impress your friends with the latest and greatest, they will not be impressed if it crashes. Which it likely will.

Comment: @paul I see crashes on 10.9, 10.10, and expect them on 10.11. Some people work professionally and run the newest software to test and review it for clients. Some people hope to help apple beta test the software so it's better and less crash-tactic when it ships. Some people develop software on a limited budget and getting it for free helps them. Don't be too negative on people wanting to try something new.

Comment: Paul does have a point with his statements.  While I don't think anyone should be negative towards others wanting to try something new, it's also fair to give warning.  Even if you do get your hands on these betas, I strongly suggest installing them only on hardware you can live without.  For most people, it's just not worth the headache.

Comment: @LloydMcFarlin I don't disagree - in fact, any upgrade even if you are going from 10.7 to 10.8 today should be taken only when you have time and a backup to reverse it should you not like it. However, we're discussing how to get something and not how stable it might or might not be... The warnings should be a sidebar and not cloud the how to get them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can sign up for the public beta (available in July) of iOS 9 and OSX El Capitan at:

[Apple Public Beta Signup](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/)

In the past, the Public Beta has delays release of a specific build a bit behind the developer betas so those builds won't be *as* potentially buggy or as up to date.

The new unified developer account costs $99 yearly. Sign up through the [Apple Developer Site](http://developer.apple.com) to get immediate access to watchOS, iOS 9 and El Capitan on June 8 and later.

- The initial El Capitan download is 6.06 GB and downloads as a redemption code from the Mac App Store.
- The initial Xcode 7 beta build is 4.22 GB and downloads from an [ADC Downloads web site](http://adcdownload.apple.com/WWDC_2015/Xcode_7_beta/Xcode_7_beta.dmg)

The big news with Xcode 7 is that it removed the requirement you be a paid developer to run your own code on your own devices. This will be huge for students of all ages with limited budgets.

> Xcode 7 and Swift now make it easier for everyone to build apps and run them directly on their Apple devices. Simply sign in with your Apple ID, and turn your idea into an app that you can touch on your iPad, iPhone, or Apple Watch. Download Xcode 7 beta and try it yourself today. Program membership is not required.

This [new Xcode is available freely to anyone today](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/) to start coding and running apps even if your Mac and iOS devices are not yet up to the announced OS. You get more tools if you join the paid program, but the basics are widely available today.